# How to integrate ACL in Symfony 3.0?

Tags: php, acl, symfony

I am new in symfony 3.0. I want to integrate ACL in my project.I am using following environment.

Symfony 3.0
OS: Windows

I did follow below link:

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html
```

When I run this command: `php bin/console init:acl`

I am getting following message:

```
[LogicException]
You must install symfony/security-acl in order to use the ACL functionality
```

Can anyone suggest how I can integrate it? Is there any demo URL and from where I can download the code?

Comment: This exception is thrown when `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\AclInterface` is missing, which indicates that something went wrong during composer install (if this is installable through composer). I'm not much into Symfony, but maby `composer dump-autoload` would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a package that Symfony needs in order to activate ACL on your project.

To install such packages, you'll need to have a working Composer installation *(Composer is a PHP dependency management scripts you can use to manage packages)*: see https://getcomposer.org/download/

Once Composer is running, you can open a console and go to the root of your project. There you can run the following command line option:

```
composer require symfony/security-acl
```

followed by:

```
composer update
```

Now you should be able to run the `php bin/console init:acl` command successfully.